# Django widgets - add class to field

Tags: python, django, forms, widget

I am trying to add class to my inputs in django `ModelForm` like this:

```
from django import forms
from .models import OrderProject

class OrderProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            if field.widget.__class__ == forms.widgets.TextInput:
                if 'class' in field.widget.attrs:
                    field.widget.attrs['class'] += 'project-form__input'
                else:
                    field.widget.attrs.update({'class':'project-form__input'})

    class Meta:
        model = OrderProject
        fields = ('name', 'customer', 'area', 'status', 'budget', 'opening_date',
                    'ending_date',)
```

Unfortunately I got error:
`'str' object has no attribute 'widget'`

Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`form.fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.fields) is a `dict` with the names of the fields as keys and the form fields as values. Iterating it, thus, produces strings. Change as follows:

```
for name, field in self.fields.items():
    # stuff with field.widget
```

Or simply (if 'stuff' doesn't involve the name, as is the case in your snippet):

```
for field in self.fields.values():
    # stuff with field.widget
```

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers True, possible. I myself would always go with the first, just to be able to access the name whenever the need arises.